# Run webpack error information: element.loader.split is not a function

Tags: webpack, babeljs

In the project I use the Babel - plugin - the import, is used to implement ant design on-demand loaded, but when I run the webpack, appear the wrong information

The following is the error message

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-
>    core/lib/LoadersList.js:58
>
> if(element.loader) return element.loader.split("!");
>
> TypeError: element.loader.split is not a function

Here is my code

webpack-config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry:  __dirname + "/src/main.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist/js",
        filename: "weitac-visual-layout.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015','stage-1'],
                    plugins: [
                        ["import", {"libraryName": "antd", "style": "css"}]
                    ]
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css?$/,
                loader: ['style-loader','css-loader'],
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

package.json

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.2.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^2.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^2.10.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the process problem

The following is the correct code

```
 {
    test: /\.css?$/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
 }
```

I was too careless, I wish you all a happy children's day ~